# android- how to get list of properties from MutableList

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-mvvm

This is my JSON :

```
{
  "cats": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "uid": "2",
      "name": "English",
      "date_update": "2019-04-22 15:31:00",
      "numCards": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I've these two classes:

```
  data class CatModelStr(
    val cats: List<Cat>
)
data class Cat(
    val date_update: String,
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val numCards: Int,
    val uid: String
)
```

I'm using MVVM and android architecture components. This is my model class for getting the data:

```
class CategoryModel(private val netManager: NetManager) {
var dateChanges: String = "null";

fun getCats(): MutableLiveData<MutableList<CatModelStr>> {
    var list = MutableLiveData<MutableList<CatModelStr>>();
    if (netManager.isConnected!!) {
        list = getCatsOnline();
    }
    return list
}

private fun getCatsOnline(): MutableLiveData<MutableList<CatModelStr>> {
    var list:MutableLiveData<MutableList<CatModelStr>> =MutableLiveData()
    val getCats = ApiConnection.client.create(Category::class.java)

    getCats.getCats(MyApp().uid, dateChanges)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { success ->
                list += success
            },{
                    error->
                Log.v("this","ErrorGetCats "+ error.localizedMessage);
            }
        )

    return list;
}

operator fun <T> MutableLiveData<MutableList<T>>.plusAssign(values: List<T>) {
    val value = this.value ?: arrayListOf()
    value.addAll(values)
    this.value = value
}
```

I have a viewModel and activity for getting the data and it works fine. The problem is this, I want to get cat values (the json properties inside cat) out of my MutableLiveData.

This is my activity code:

```
vm.getCats().observe(this, Observer {
        if(it!=null) {
            rc_cats.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            pb.visibility=View.GONE
            catAdapter.reloadData(it)
        }
    })
```

The value is `MutableList<CatModelStr>` and I need Cat.

How can I get Cat out of MutableList?

Answer (score 1):

What I am getting is that you don't need `MutableList` list from your response instead you need `CatModelStr`

you need to make the following changes from starting i guess.

```
class CategoryModel(private val netManager: NetManager) {
var dateChanges: String = "null";

fun getCats(): MutableLiveData<CatModelStr> {
    var list = MutableLiveData<CatModelStr>();
    if (netManager.isConnected!!) {
        list = getCatsOnline();
    }
    return list
}

private fun getCatsOnline(): MutableLiveData<CatModelStr> {
    var list:MutableLiveData<CatModelStr> = MutableLiveData()
    val getCats = ApiConnection.client.create(Category::class.java)

    getCats.getCats(MyApp().uid, dateChanges)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { success ->
                list.setValue(success)
            },{
                    error->
                Log.v("this","ErrorGetCats "+ error.localizedMessage);
                list.setValue(null)
            }
        )

    return list;
}
```

and now if observe this you will get `CatModelStr` instead of `MutableList` and the reason is that your `JSON` is giving you data in format CatModelStr, you are trying to get this unnecessarily in MutableList which also won't work and you can't parse your JSON given the format.